# Multiple slice from an Iterator - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have this piece of code:

```
import itertools as it

....

temp_list = []
for elem in it.islice(myIter, 0, 3):
    temp_list.append(elem[0])

print(temp_list)
```

Let's assume that the lenght of `myIter` is fixed but not known a priori, let's say 100 for this example. With the above code, i can put in the `temp_list` the first 3 elements of `myIter`.
What i want to do is to continue to append in the `temp_list` all the elements of `myIter` until all the elements of `myIter` is in `temp_list`.

How can i do this?

**EDIT**

the `temp_list` should be a list of list. So in the first position let's say  `temp_list[][0]` i have the first 3 element of the `myIter`, then i want the second slice (elements from 4 to 6) in the `temp_list[][1]` and so on until `myIter` is at the end

Comment: So you want to remove the `islice` and iterate over the entirety of `myIter`?

Comment: or just `temp_list.extend(myIter)`?

Comment: nope, i'll explain better in the origianl question

Comment: Dupe: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](//stackoverflow.com/q/312443)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
temp_list = list(myIter)
print(temp_list)
```